# Normal unit vector

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vectors, curves, involutions

I am looking at the following exercise:

[image]

I have done the following about the second part, about the signed curvature of $\iota$ :

The signed curvature of $\gamma$ is different from the signed curvature of $\iota$, right?

So, let $\kappa_s$ be the signed curvature of $\gamma$ and $\kappa_{s, \iota}$ the signed curvature of $\iota$.

We have $$\iota '(s)=\gamma '(s)-\gamma '(s)+(l-s)\gamma ''(s) \Rightarrow \iota '(s)=(l-s)\gamma '' (s) \tag{1}$$

We define as the unit tangent vector $\textbf{t}$, the signed unit normal vector $\textbf{n}_{s, \iota}$ and the signed curvature $\kappa_{s, \iota}$ of $\iota$ the corresponding quantities of the unit speed reparametrization of $\tilde{\iota}(a)$, where $a$ is the arc length of $\iota$. 
So, $$\textbf{t}=\frac{\iota ' (s)}{\|\iota ' (s)\|}=\frac{\iota '(s)}{a'(s)}$$ 
Therefore, $$\iota '(s)=a'(s)\textbf{t}$$

We have that if $\iota$ is a unit-speed plane curve, then $$\textbf{n}_{s, \iota } ' =-\kappa_{s, \iota} \iota'$$

Generalizing this formula for a regular curve, not necessarily unit-speed, we have $$\textbf{n}_{s,\iota } ' =-\kappa_{s,\iota}a'(s)\textbf{t} \tag{2}$$

$$(1) \Rightarrow a'(s)\textbf{t}=(l-s)\gamma ''(s) \Rightarrow a'(s) \textbf{t}=(l-s)\kappa_s \textbf{n}_s$$

$$(2) \Rightarrow \textbf{n}_{s, \iota } '=-\kappa_{s, \iota} (l-s)\kappa_s \textbf{n}_s$$

Which is the relation between the normal unit vector of the curve and normal unit vector of the involute of the curve?

Answer (score 3):

Yummy. A bounty. :)

We have:
$$\iota=\gamma+(l-s)\gamma'$$
$$\dot\iota=(l-s)\gamma''$$
$$\ddot\iota=-\gamma'' + (l-s)\gamma'''$$

Since it is given that $\kappa_s > 0$, it follows that the curve bends continuously in the counter clock direction, meaning $n_s=n$ and $\kappa_s = \kappa$. Since the string is wound around the curve, we can conclude that $\iota$ is also counter clock wise, meaning $n_{\iota,s} = n_\iota$ and $\kappa_{\iota,s} = \kappa_\iota$.

With the general formula for $\kappa_\iota$ we get:
$$\kappa_\iota = \frac{\|\dot\iota \times \ddot\iota\|}{\|\dot\iota\|^3}
= \frac{\|(l-s)\gamma'' \times (-\gamma'' + (l-s)\gamma''')\|}{\|(l-s)\gamma''||^3}
= \frac{\|\gamma'' \times \gamma'''\|}{(l-s)\kappa^3}
= \frac{\|\kappa n \times (\kappa'n + \kappa n')\|}{(l-s)\kappa^3}
= \frac{\|n \times n'\|}{(l-s)\kappa}
= \frac{\|n \times -\kappa t\|}{(l-s)\kappa}
= \frac{1}{l-s}
$$

Btw, the unit vectors are perpendicular.

Comment: How did you get the last equality of the first line at the calculation of $\kappa_{\iota}$? Isn't it as follows? $$\frac{||(l-s)\gamma'' \times (-\gamma'' +(l-s)\gamma''')||}{||(l-s)\gamma''||^3}=\frac{||(l-s)\gamma'' \times (-1)\gamma''+(l-s)\gamma'' \times  (l-s)\gamma''')||}{(l-s)||\gamma''||^3}\\ =\frac{||-(l-s)\gamma'' \times \gamma'' +(l-s)^2\gamma'' \times  \gamma''')||}{(l-s)||\gamma''||^3}=\frac{||(l-s)^2\gamma'' \times  \gamma''')||}{(l-s)||\gamma''||^3}\\ =\frac{(l-s)^2||\gamma'' \times  \gamma''')||}{(l-s)||\gamma''||^3}=\frac{(l-s)||\gamma'' \times  \gamma''')||}{||\gamma''||^3}$$

Comment: Almost. In your first line we've lost a power of 3 for $(l-s)$. :eek: 

Oh, and let's assume that $l\ge s$.

Furthermore, $||\gamma''|| = \kappa$.

Comment: I see... Now I don't understand the last two equalities... We use the Frenet-Serret equalities, right? It as follows, right? $$\frac{|| n \times  n'||}{(l-s)\kappa}=\frac{|| n \times  (-\kappa t+\tau b)||}{(l-s)\kappa}=\frac{||(-\kappa  n \times  t+\tau n \times b)||}{(l-s)\kappa}$$ How do we continue?

Comment: Since we're in $\mathbb R^2$, $\tau=0$. And $||n\times t||$ is always 1.

Comment: Is $n$ the signed unit normal vector or the unit normal vector?

Comment: I intended the unit normal. Anyway, in this particular case it's the same as the signed unit normal. That is because it is given that $\kappa_s>0$.

Comment: I've added an explanation that $\kappa_s=\kappa$ and the same for all related signed-ness stuff.

Comment: Could you explain to me why when the curve bends continuously in the counter clock direction, we have that $n_s=n$ ?

Comment: The unit normal is directed in the direction that the curve bends, which would be to the left. The signed unit normal is the unit tangent rotated to the left. In other words, both normals point in the same direction.

Comment: Why is the direction to the left? I got stuck right now...

Comment: Let's put it differently. We have that $\gamma'' = \kappa n = \kappa_s n_s$. It is given that $\kappa_s > 0$, and we always have $\kappa \ge 0$. Therefore $n=n_s$ and $\kappa = \kappa_s$.

Comment: We have that $\kappa_s (s) >0 \ \ \forall s$, so $\kappa_s=\kappa$. Then $\gamma '' =\kappa_s n_s=\kappa n_s$. How did you get the relation $\gamma'' = \kappa n = \kappa_s n_s$ ?

Comment: It follows from the respective definitions: $\kappa=||\gamma''||$, $n=\frac{\gamma''}{\kappa}$, $\kappa_s=\gamma''\cdot n_s$.

Comment: Why does the definition $n=\frac{\gamma ''}{\kappa}$ stand? I got stuck right now...

Comment: Which definition do you have for n?

Comment: Now I found the definition you used in my book!! $$$$ We have that $\kappa_s(s)>0 \ \forall s$, so $\kappa_s=\kappa$. So, from the formula $\kappa_s =\gamma '' \cdot n_s$ we get $\kappa=\gamma '' \cdot n_s$. Since $n=\frac{\gamma ''}{\kappa} \Rightarrow \kappa n=\gamma '' \Rightarrow \kappa =\gamma '' \cdot n$, we get $\gamma '' \cdot n_s =\gamma '' \cdot n $. How can we continue to get rid of $\gamma ''$ ?

Comment: We have that $\kappa_s(s)>0 \ \forall s$, so $\kappa_s=\kappa$. So, from the formula $\kappa_s =\gamma '' \cdot n_s$ we get $\kappa=\gamma '' \cdot n_s \Rightarrow \gamma '' =\kappa n_s$. We have that  $n=\frac{\gamma ''}{\kappa} \Rightarrow n=\frac{\kappa n_s}{\kappa}=n_s$. So $n=n_s$. Is this correct?

Comment: That doesn't quite right. Formally we cannot conclude that $\kappa_s=\kappa$, and from $\kappa=\gamma''\cdot n_s$ we cannot conclude that the vectors $\gamma''$ and $n_s$ point in the same direction (although they do). However, we do know that $\gamma''$, $n$, and $n_s$ are all parallel and perpendicular to the tangent.

Comment: Why can we not conclude that $\kappa_s=\kappa$ ? It stands tha $\kappa=|\kappa_s|$ and since $\kappa_s (s)>0, \forall s$ do we not conclude that $\kappa=|\kappa_s|=\kappa_s$ ?

Comment: That's fine. We just needed additionally that $\kappa=|\kappa_s|$.

Comment: So, we have $$\kappa=\kappa_s=\gamma '' \cdot n_s \tag {1}$$ We also have $$n=\frac{\gamma '' }{\kappa} \Rightarrow \gamma '' =\kappa n \tag {2}$$ Therefore, from the relations $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $$\kappa=\kappa n\cdot n_s \Rightarrow n \cdot n_s=1$$ From the latter we get that $n$ and $n_s$ are parallel to each other, right? But how can we conclude that they have also the same direction? Or can't we?

Comment: Yes we can. If they had opposite direction, the dot product would be $-1$.

Comment: Ok... I see... So from the relation $n \cdot n_s=1$ we conclude that $n=n_s$, right?

Comment: I haven't really understood why it stands also for $\iota$ that $\kappa_{\iota}=\kappa_{s, \iota}$ and $n_{\iota}=n_{s, \iota}$. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: I guess we can prove it other than with just words. We have $\tilde\iota'' = \kappa_{\iota,s}n_{\iota,s} = \kappa_\iota n_\iota = \frac{\dot\iota \times \ddot\iota}{\|\dot\iota\|^3} = \frac{n \times -t}{l-s} = \frac{t \times n}{l-s}$. Since we know that $t \times n = t \times n_s$, it follows in the same way as before that $\kappa_{\iota,s} = \kappa_\iota$ and $n_{\iota,s} = n_\iota$.

Comment: Ahaa... Ok!! $$$$ Could you give ma a hint how we can show the first part, that the endpoint of the string traces out the curve $$\iota=\gamma+(l-s)\gamma'$$ ?

Comment: I suggest to make a drawing. In words: when the wire has been wound by a distance $s$, it coincides with the curve from $\gamma(0)$ up to $\gamma(s)$. After that the wire follows a straight line from $\gamma(s)$ in the direction of its tangent, which is $\gamma'(s)$. The remaining length of the wire is $(l -s)$. Since the curve is unit speed we can multiply those two and add it to $\gamma(s)$. That is, we get $\iota(s)=\gamma(s) + (l-s)\gamma'(s)$.

Comment: After having that the wire coincides with the curve from $\gamma (0)$ to $\gamma (s)$, why does the wire follow a **straight line** from $\gamma (s)$ in the direction of its tangent?

Comment: Because the string is kept taught. That means it is following a straight line, which represents the shortest distance between 2 points.

Comment: You mean that the part of the string from $\gamma (s)$ till its endpoind is a straight line parallel to tangent $\gamma '(s)$, right? Or have I understood it wrong?

Comment: Also, I haven't really understood why we multiply $(l-s)$ with $\gamma '(s)$... Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Yes. The total length is $l$. A length $s$ is wound around the curve. That leaves a length $(l-s)$. And $\gamma'(s)$ is a unit vector in the direction that the remaining length goes.

Comment: Since it is a straight line do we use the equation of a line $a+tb$, where the line passes through $a$ and is parallel to $b$ ?

Comment: Yes. And if the direction were different, there would be an angle where the string connects to the curve. In such a case, the string can be drawn tauter.

Comment: At this equation do we take $t=l-s$ ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you closed the bounty early. Is that legal? Well, I'll show you what I did for this anyway.

For convenience I'll use $g$ in place of $\gamma$ and $h$ for the involute of $g.$ I'll often suppress the arc-length parameter $s.$ Some observations:

i)$h' = (l-s)g''$

ii) $|g''|' = (g''\cdot g''')/|g''|$

iii) $g''' = -|g''|^2g' + cg''.$

iii) deserves some explanation. We know $g',g''$ are orthogonal, so $g'\cdot g'' \equiv 0.$ Differentiate that to get $|g''|^2 + g'\cdot g''' \equiv 0.$ Now $g'$ is a unit vector. So resolving $g'''$ as an orthogonal sum with respect to $g',g''$ gives iii), where $c$ is a function of $s$ that we don't need too much information about.

Denote the unit tangent vector of $h$ by $T.$ By i) we have $T= g''/|g''|.$ Using ii) and iii) we get

$$\tag 1 \frac{dT}{ds} = \frac{|g''|g''' - g''|g''|'}{|g''|^2} = -|g''|g'.$$

Let $s_1$ denote arc length along the curve $h.$ Then $d s_1/ ds = (l-s)|g''(s)|.$ Using this and $(1),$ we get

$$\frac{dT}{ds_1} = \frac{dT/ds}{ds_1/ds } = \frac{-|g''|g'}{(l-s)|g''(s)|} = \frac{-1}{l-s}.$$

So the curvature along the involute $h$ is $1/(l-s).$ How do we know this is the signed curvature? That's easy: $g''$ is a positive multiple of $ig'$ (thinking of $g',g''$ as complex numbers), and the same relation therefore holds for $dT/d s_1$ and $T$ because the first is a negative mulitple of $g'$ and the second is a positive multiple of $g''.$